# Traverse a list of lists and a list together

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists, well a list whose elements can have an attribute which is a list

```
a =  [ob1,ob2,ob3,ob4,ob52,ob7,ob8,ob10]
ob52.list = [ob5,ob6]
ob82.list = [ob8,ob9]
```

and a list

```
b= [b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10]
```

both lists contain 10 elements,ie to say they will **always** contain the same number of elements.

What I want to do is  `ob[i].b = b[i]` if `ob.has_list == False` for all i.
If `ob` has a list assign each element of `ob[i].list` the corresponding `b[i]`

I have solved it like this(quite C'ish),and was wondering if there is a simpler way.

```
i=0;k=0;j=0
for k in xrange(0,len(a)):
    if k<i:
        continue
    if a[j].has_list:
        for q in a[j].list:
            q.b = b[i]
            i+=1
    else:
        a[j].b = b[i]
        i+=1
    j+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both lists have the same length when `a` is flattened, you can flatten `a`, then you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
import itertools

flat_a = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
            (e.list if e.has_list else (e,))
                for e in a)

for xa, xb in zip(flat_a, b):
    xa.b = xb
```

Comment: This doesn't work as both lists are not equal in length ,they are equal in length if you include the sub-lists.